# rails - grape api error calling classes for version-ed api

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, versioning, grape-api

I'm trying to call version specific classes for versioned api(rails-grape) and get error

```
 NameError (uninitialized constant API::V1::XMLResponses):
09:23:36 web.1     |   app/api/v1/base.rb
```

my directory structure

```
app/
  api/
    v1/
      xmlresponses/
         phonebook.rb   
      api.rb
    v2/
      xmlresponses/ 
      api.rb
    api.rb
```

api.rb
require 'v1/base.rb'
require 'v2/base.rb'

```
module  API
  class Base < Grape::API
    mount API::V1 => '/'
    mount API::V2 => '/v2/'
  end
end
```

in v1/base.rb i access classes for this version of api

> V1::XMLResponses::Phonebook::getall()

Please, could you tell me why do i get this error?

Thanks for your answer, I've  created simple app that demonstrates how it's done https://github.com/Asmmund/grape_versioning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could be simply something wrong in your module structure.
Maybe a missing `require`.

I would write something like this:

```
/foo
  v1/
  |_ responses/
  |  |_ time.rb
  |
  |_ base.rb

  v2/
  |  
  |_ base.rb

  api.rb
  config.ru
```

The files:

```
# api.rb`

require 'grape'
require './v1/base.rb'
require './v2/base.rb'

module FooBar
  module API
    class Base < Grape::API
      mount API::V1 => '/'
      mount API::V2 => '/v2/'
    end
  end
end


# v1/base.rb
require_relative './responses/time.rb'

module FooBar
  module API
    class V1 < Grape::API
      get 'foo' do
        "foo"
      end
      get 'time' do
        API::Responses::Time.api_time
      end
    end
  end
end

# v1/responses/time.rb
module FooBar
  module API
    module Responses
      class Time
        def self.api_time
          "API time"
        end
      end
    end
  end
end

# v2/base.rb
module FooBar
  module API
    class V2 < Grape::API
      get 'bar' do
        "bar"
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Then in `config.ru`

```
# config.ru
require './api.rb'
run FooBar::API::Base
```

Run with:

```
thin start
...
curl 0.0.0.0:3000/foo
=> foo
curl 0.0.0.0:3000/v2/bar
=> bar
curl 0.0.0.0:3000/time
=> API time
```